# Вручную изменить код ответа от сервера

Tags: node.js, http, rest

Добрый день, подскажите как можно вручную изменить ответ от сервера?
Есть, код:

```
router.get("/auth/:token", function(req,res){

    var query = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?";
    var table = ["users", "token", req.params.token];

    query = mysql.format(query,table);

    connection.query(query,function(error, result){

        if(error) {
            res.json("Ошибка подключения к БД!");
        } else {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                res.json(result);
                return true;
            } else {
                res.json("Ошибка");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

На фронтенд стороне код ответа всегда 200, не зависимо от выборки. Как сделать чтобы если result.length === 0, сервер посылал код 403, а не 200?

Answer (score -1):

Нашел, все было проще чем казалось: `res.status('403');`